# Can attributes be applied to constructor parameters?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, compiler-bug

Clang 8.0.0 and GCC 9.1.0 seem to disagree as to whether this is valid code.

```
struct Foo {
  Foo([[maybe_unused]] int x) {}
};
int main() {}
```

Clang produces no warnings (even with `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic`) but GCC produces this error:

```
test.cpp:2:7: error: expected unqualified-id before '[' token
    2 |   Foo([[maybe_unused]] int x) {}
      |       ^
test.cpp:2:7: error: expected ')' before '[' token
    2 |   Foo([[maybe_unused]] int x) {}
      |      ~^
      |       )
```

So which compiler has a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they can be applied. The standard allows this.

> **10.6.6 Maybe unused attribute [[dcl.attr.unused]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.attr.unused)**
>   ...
>   [2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.attr.unused#2) The attribute may be applied to the declaration of a class, a typedef-name, a variable, a non-static data member, a function, an enumeration, or an enumerator.

So Clang is correct here and this is a GCC bug. 
A bug report has already been filed for this titled: [maybe_unused attribute triggers syntax error when used on first argument to a constructor](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=81429)

Comment: Spooky how the bug report also writes `Foo([[maybe_unused]] int x)`. It's kind of unfortunate that the report has been open for so long without being fixed.

Comment: It has not even been assigned to anyone after almost two years.

Answer (score 4):

**Your code is valid**

> The `[[maybe_unused]]` attribute can be applied to the declaration of a struct, enum, union,
>   typedef, variable (including member variables), function, or enumerator. Implementations are
>   encouraged to not emit a diagnostic when such an entity is unused or when the entity is used despite
>   being marked as `[[maybe_unused]]`.

However there is already a bug report for this in `gcc` [maybe_unused attribute triggers syntax error when used on first argument to a constructor](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=81429) . `gcc` probably is not able to parse it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely an issue in your GCC compile line. 
I receive a similar error when running the following line:

```
gcc *.cpp -o run_me
```

However, no issue is given when using the following line:

```
gcc -std=c++17 *.cpp -o run_me -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic
```

Running with standard c++11 will give the warning "use of the 'maybe_unused' attribute is a C++17 extension". Be sure to use c++17 when compiling this code.